# iPhone won't ring, only vibrates

Tags: audio, iphone, call

I have my iPhone5 set on "Vibrate on Ring"  and the volume is not on mute, but when someone calls, it only vibrates. I've included it in Notifications Center, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Do Not Disturb has also been turned off. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you have checked that the hardware switch on the side of the phone isn't set to silent?

Right near the volume buttons is a switch, if it shows red then your phone is on silent, flick it up and the phone is no longer on silent.

Comment: -_-. I have a rugged case that covers that switch up. I didn't realize it was off when I put it on. Thanks!

Comment: Bet you felt like a nong when you saw it :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the won't ring problem by inserting & removing my headphones jack. This should work if your phone is stuck in headphones mode.

Thanks to http://www.unlockboot.com/2015/11/how-to-fix-iphone-wont-ring-problem.html